# Potential leak detected in iphone App when Analysed

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

im building an app which grabs all the contacts from iPhone book and filter it my names having only emails. i use the following function for that (filtering with names having email address)

```
- (long)personRecord:(ABRecordRef)paramPerson{

    if(paramPerson == nil){

        NSLog(@"The given Person is Null");
    }

    ABMutableMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(paramPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if(emails == nil){

        return 0;
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld",ABMultiValueGetCount(emails));
    // return (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails));

    return (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails));
}
```

When analysed I'm geting potential leak

[image]

how can  i resolve this Leak ....????

Comment: I don't know anything about this ABRecord class, but since you are using a method with the word 'copy' in it, my assumption is you need to release the ABMutableMultiValueRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a copy of that object from `ABRecordRef`. So you need to release it.

Change your method like;

```
- (long)personRecord:(ABRecordRef)paramPerson
  {

    if(paramPerson == nil)
    {

        NSLog(@"The given Person is Null");
    }

    ABMutableMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(paramPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if(emails == nil)
    {

        return 0;
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld",ABMultiValueGetCount(emails));
    // return (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails));

    long count = ABMultiValueGetCount(emails);
     CFRelease(emails);
     return count;
}
```

Comment: @PriyanHaridas: with pleasure

Answer (score 2):

You are not releasing the object and thats why it causes memory leak.Try this code.This will fix the leak and also release the object at the right place.Hope this helps you

```
              CFRelease(emails);
```